# obtener id de boton mediante javascript

Tags: php, javascript

tengo el siguiente problema
tengo una lista de datos obtenidas de una consulta al base de datos, pero requiero realizar un botón en donde pueda obtener la id para realización la eliminación de alguna especifica, tengo la estructura del javascript pero al momento de hacer click, solamente me identifica el id del primer dato, sin importar a que registro le de.

```
echo "<div id = 'inv".$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV']."'>";
            echo '<div id="pro'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'" class ="col-md-8">

                    <button onclick = "elimi()" id="remov" data-id = "'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm eliInv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                    <input type = "hidden" name ="idinvG[]" value = "'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'">
                    <textarea name ="nombreG[]" class="fieldname form-control" placeholder="Nombre del proyecto" required>'.$liInv['NOMBRE'].'</textarea>
                    <textarea name = "sintesisG[]" class="fieldname form-control" placeholder=" Sintesis del proyecto" required>'.$liInv['DESCRIPCION'].'</textarea>
                    <textarea name ="lineaG[]" class="fieldname form-control" placeholder=" Linea de Investigacion a la que pertenece" required>'.$liInv['LINEA'].'</textarea>';
           echo' </div>';

          echo '<div id="opc'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'" class ="subfielwapeper">';
                  $invD = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PLANPTCINVESTDETALLE");
                        while($liDinv = mysqli_fetch_array($invD)){

                            $invDet = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PLANPTCINVESTDETALLE_DETALLE WHERE CVE_PLANPTCINVESTDETALLE = '".$liDinv['CVE_PLANPTDETALLE']."' AND CVE_PLANPTCINVESTIGACION = '".$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV']."'");
                            $rowInvD = mysqli_fetch_array($invDet);

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($invDet)>0){
                                echo '<p class="subwrapper"><label class="form-check-label" cheked><input type="checkbox" name = "invDetG'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'[]" value="'.$liDinv['CVE_PLANPTDETALLE'].'"  class="form-check-input" checked /> '.$liDinv['descripcion'].'</label></p>';
                            }else{
                                echo '<p class="subwrapper"><label class="form-check-label" cheked><input type="checkbox" name = "invDetG'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'[]" value="'.$liDinv['CVE_PLANPTDETALLE'].'"  class="form-check-input" /> '.$liDinv['descripcion'].'</label></p>';
                            }
          }
          echo' </div>';
      echo' </div>';


function elimi(){

var id = $('#remov').data("id");    
alert(id);

}
```

Comment: El id debe de ser unico.  Si estas repitiendo el mismo id en un bucle no te va a funcionar.  Necesitas usar clases en lugar de id.

Comment: hola!, gracias por leerme, igual lo intente con clases, pero ni asi :(

Comment: como llamo una di dinamina en javascript en caso de poner lo siguiente??: id="remov'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV']."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando el contexto `this` asi:

```
<button onclick = "elimi(this)" id="remov" data-id = "'.$liInv['CVE_PLANPTCINV'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm eliInv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

Y luego en javascript obtienes el valor que quieres asi:

```
function elimi(boton){    
  var id = $(boton).data("id");    
  alert(id);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

como te comentan, es recomendable no repetir los `id`, pero en cuanto a tu pregunta, puedes obtener la propiedad `data-id` haciendo uso del método `.attr()`, y mediante `$(this)`, haces referencia exáctamente al elemento que estés clickeando, de esta manera:

```js
$('body button').on('click', function() {
  let idButton = $(this).attr('data-id');
  alert(idButton);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="boton1" data-id="Boton_1">Botón 1</button><br>
  <button id="boton2" data-id="Boton_2">Botón 2</button><br>
  <button id="boton3" data-id="Boton_3">Botón 3</button><br>
</div>
```